# Ehcache 2.10.6 hit statistic not being incremented

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, ehcache, spring-boot-actuator

I've set up a cache in one of my projects, along with the custom health indicator as below:

```
@Component
public class CustomHealthIndicator extends AbstractHealthIndicator
{

    @Override
    protected void doHealthCheck(Health.Builder builder)
    {
        CacheManager cacheManagerInstance = CacheManager.getInstance();
        Ehcache cache = cacheManagerInstance.getCache("myCache");

        builder.up()
                .withDetail("Cache Size", cache.getSize())
                .withDetail("Cache Hit Count", cache.getStatistics().cacheHitCount())
                .withDetail("Cache Miss Count", cache.getStatistics().cacheMissCount())
                .withDetail("Cache Put Count", cache.getStatistics().cachePutCount())
                .withDetail("Cache Remove Count", cache.getStatistics().cacheRemoveCount())
                .withDetail("Cache Expired Count", cache.getStatistics().cacheExpiredCount());
    }
```

When I run it locally and go to localhost:8080/actuator/health all the other statistics update but the hits doesn't.

> {"status":"UP","details":{"Cache Size":9,"Cache Hit Count":0,"Cache
>   Miss Count":9,"Cache Put Count":9,"Cache Remove Count":0,"Cache
>   Expired Count":0}}

My code accessing the cache in my other project is:

```
Cacheable cachedResult = CacheManager.getInstance().getCache(request);
if (cachedResult != null)
{
    CustomResponse response = (CustomResponse) cachedResult.getObject();
    return response;
}
```

I can confirm that this block is entered and that there actually is data in the cache.

I have no idea why the hits statistic isn't being updated. Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out my objects were not being serialized correctly, so when it was searching for them in the cache they were not being found.